# Function as a KnockoutJS observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following script (see below). I have two questions regarding it:

1.What does the following line mean in the context of Knockoutjs?

```
ko.observable(null);
```

2.How can I invoke a function not yet defined as in here:

```
that.activePollingXhr(...
```

Here is the full script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function ChatViewModel() {

        var that = this;

        that.userName = ko.observable('');
        that.chatContent = ko.observable('');
        that.message = ko.observable('');
        that.messageIndex = ko.observable(0);
        that.activePollingXhr = ko.observable(null);


        var keepPolling = false;

        that.joinChat = function() {
            if (that.userName().trim() != '') {
                keepPolling = true;
                pollForMessages();
            }
        }

        function pollForMessages() {
            if (!keepPolling) {
                return;
            }
            var form = $("#joinChatForm");


            that.activePollingXhr($.ajax({url: form.attr("action"), type: "GET", data: form.serialize(), cache: false,
                success: function(messages) {
                    console.log(messages);
                    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        that.chatContent(that.chatContent() + messages[i] + "\n");
                        that.messageIndex(that.messageIndex() + 1);
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    if (xhr.statusText != "abort" && xhr.status != 503) {
                        resetUI();
                        console.error("Unable to retrieve chat messages. Chat ended.");
                    }
                },
                complete: pollForMessages
            }));
            $('#message').focus();
        }

        that.postMessage = function() {
            if (that.message().trim() != '') {
                var form = $("#postMessageForm");
                $.ajax({url: form.attr("action"), type: "POST",
                    data: "message=[" + that.userName() + "] " + $("#postMessageForm input[name=message]").val(),
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.error("Error posting chat message: status=" + xhr.status + ", statusText=" + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
                that.message('');
            }
        }

        that.leaveChat = function() {
            that.activePollingXhr(null);
            resetUI();
            this.userName('');
        }

        function resetUI() {
            keepPolling = false;
            that.activePollingXhr(null);
            that.message('');
            that.messageIndex(0);
            that.chatContent('');
        }

    }

    //Activate knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new ChatViewModel());

});
```

Comment: could you elaborate some more on the 2nd question?

Comment: I meant the `activePollingXhr` is not defined or implemented anywhere in the code. How then can I invoke it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ko.observable(null);` creates an observable with a value of `null`. Nothing different than `ko.observable(5);`, where the value would be `5`.
2. I see that you're using the `that.activePollingXhr` observable by passing it the result of an ajax call. However, this call is asynchronous and `$.ajax` doesn't return the data it got from the server, but rather a jquery deferred. You need to use `that.activePollingXhr` insude the `success` callback. Here's is how your code might look like:

   ```
   $.ajax({url: form.attr("action"), type: "GET", data: form.serialize(), cache: false,
       success: function(messages) {
           console.log(messages);
           for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
               that.chatContent(that.chatContent() + messages[i] + "\n");
               that.messageIndex(that.messageIndex() + 1);
           }
           that.activePollingXhr(messages); // <-- Note where the call to activePollingXhr is
       },
       error: function(xhr) {
           if (xhr.statusText != "abort" && xhr.status != 503) {
               resetUI();
               console.error("Unable to retrieve chat messages. Chat ended.");
           }
       },
       complete: pollForMessages
   });
   ```

As for the comment under your question: `that.activePollingXhr`  is defined as `that.activePollingXhr = ko.observable(null);` - an observable with value of `null`.

Answer (score 3):

That just initializes an observable with `null` as the initial value.

If you need to invoke a function that is an observable, just add a second set of parenthesis.

```
that.activePollingXhr()()
```